# We need help to cache 60sec information in laravel

Tags: laravel, caching, random

we need your help to cache information in laravel. I want cache random information 
60 seconds and after 60 seconds when I click on the same value url again the url information would be new again.

Example:

```
url - domain.com/cats/2 <br>
It's take random from cats.txt file:<br>

Cats 1 - Richy,
Cats 2 - Tom,
Cats 3 - Luka <br>
```

And i want this information cache 60 seconds, after 60 second I again click url domain.com/cats/2 and information random from cats.txt new, exampe:

```
Cats 1 = Justin,
Cats 2 = Edvinas,
Cats 3 = Dzho.
```

Controller:
https://pastebin.com/C4eLAYfw

Route: 
https://pastebin.com/3PuaL82L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cache::remember` works for your use case perfectly. According to the documentation;

> Sometimes you may wish to retrieve an item from the cache, but also store a default value if the requested item doesn't exist. For example, you may wish to retrieve all users from the cache or, if they don't exist, retrieve them from the database and add them to the cache. You may do this using the Cache::remember method

```
public function index($value)
{
    return Cache::remember('your-cat-key', 1, function () use ($value) {
        return $this->getRandomCats($value);
    });
}

public function getRandomCats($value)
{
    $f_contents = file('cats.txt');
    $line1 = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
    $line2 = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
    $line3 = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
    $Cat1 = $line1;
    $Cat2 = $line2;
    $Cat3 = $line3;

    return compact('Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Cache with a Redis store driver or similar and just set the expiration time to 60 seconds. [See the Laravel docs for Laravel Cache.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache#storing-items-in-the-cache)

```php
// Set Item in Cache
Cache::put('key', 'value', $seconds);

// Get Item from Cache
$value = Cache::get('key');

// Check Item existence in Cache
if (Cache::has('key')) {
    //
}
```